# Github actions - How to Download the workflow logs using Github API?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I am trying to get the build logs when the workflow is finished. I have followed this [documentaion](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-runs#download-workflow-run-logs). But I am getting the following error:

```
"message": "Not Found",
"documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest"
```

I don't know what I did wrong here. someone guide me on how I can download the logs.

**Workflow.yml:**

```
name: Get logs

on: push

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: get workflow logs
    permissions:
      actions: read
    steps:
    - name: Hello World
      id: helloresponse
      run: echo Hello, world!

    - name: create log
      if: always()
      id: createlog
      run: |
        curl --request GET \
          -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
          --header 'authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}' \
          --header 'content-type: application/json' \
          https://api.github.com/repos/${{github.owner}}/${{github.repository}}/actions/runs/${{ github.run_id }}/log
```

Comment: Does it work outside of a workflow? What happens if you run this curl command locally? Are you sure the log is already available via the API _while_ the job is still running?

Comment: when I run locally also get the same error "message not found".  yeah, the step name hello world log is already available.

Comment: A "not found" (404) can also be caused by an invalid token. Which token did you use with curl on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

I think the endpoint ends with `logs` not `log`

```
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-runs#download-workflow-run-logs
```